# Keras target dimensions mismatch

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Attempting a single-label classification problem with `num_classes = 73`

Here's my simplified Keras model:

```
num_classes = 73
batch_size = 4

train_data_list = [training_file_names list here..]
validation_data_list = [ validation_file_names list here..]

training_generator = DataGenerator(train_data_list, batch_size, num_classes)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(validation_data_list, batch_size, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, input_shape=(15,120), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv1D(16, 3, strides=1, activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=100,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Here's my `DataGenerator`'s `__get_item__` method:

```
def __get_item__(self):
    X = np.zeros((self.batch_size,15,120))
    y = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1 ,self.n_classes))
    for i in range(self.batch_size):
      X_row = some_method_that_gives_X_of_15x20_dim()   
      target = some_method_that_gives_target()    
      one_hot = keras.utils.to_categorical(target, num_classes=self.n_classes)
      X[i] = X_row
      y[i] = one_hot
    return X, y
```

Since my `X` values are correctly returned with dimension `(batch_size, 15, 120)`, I am not showing it here. My issue is with the y value returned.

`y` returned from this generator method has a shape of `(batch_size, 1, 73)` as one hot encoded label for the 73 classes, which I think is the correct shape to return.

However Keras gives the following error for the last layer:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 1, 73)

Since the batch size is 4, I think the target batch should also be 3 dimensional (4,1,73). Why is then Keras expecting the last layer to be 2 dimensions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you model' s summary shows that in the output layer there should be only 2 dimensions, (None, 73)

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_7 (Conv1D)            (None, 13, 32)            11552     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_8 (Conv1D)            (None, 11, 16)            1552      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 176)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 73)                12921     
=================================================================
Total params: 26,025
Trainable params: 26,025
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Since dimension of your target is (batch_size, 1, 73), you can just change to (batch_size, 73) in order for your model to run